# How to install and use Kmeans in Chaquopy in android studio?

Tags: python, android, android-studio, k-means, chaquopy

I am trying to get the RGB values from images using K-means clustering. The value of k is decided based on the Adaptive K value method.

Answer (score 0):

Find a package that implements this algorithm, such as [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html), and then [install it in your build.gradle file](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html#android-requirements).

Comment: While installing kmeans directly from -->  pip {
              
             install "kmeans"
            }  is throwing errors

Comment: The [`kmeans`](https://pypi.org/project/kmeans/#history) package looks abandoned. Try using a different implementation, such as the scikit-learn one linked in my answer.